# Etimología de "cachonda"

Tags: etimología, adjetivos

Covarrubias, en su [*Tesoro de la Lengua Castellana o Española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=K10MJdL7pGIC), define:

> CACHONDA, quasi catulonda la perra que esta salida, y se va a buscar los perros, en especial los jouenes, que llamamos cachorros.

¿Cuál es la etimología de **cachonda**?

Comment: Diría que con lo de _quasi catulonda_ te está diciendo la posible etimología.

Answer (score 8):

Me intrigó en la definición que las palabras *cachonda* y *cachorro* se parecieran tanto. Y, por lo que se ve, no iba muy desencaminado. Cito a Corominas:

> CACHORRO 'cría del perro y de ciertas fieras', 1490. Origen incierto, parece ser derivado de *cacho*, que hoy solo subsiste en acepciones secundarias [...] pero que significaría primitivamente 'cachorro'; es probable que proceda del lat. vg. *CATTULUS, por reduplicación afectiva del lat. CATŬLUS 'cachorro'. Del propio *cacho* derivan: *cachillada* 'parto de animal que da a luz muchos hijuelos', 1720; *cachondo*, h. 1450, 'dominado por el apetito venéreo' (esp. la perra), reducción de *cachiondo*, formado como *torionda* de *toro* y *verrionda* de VERRES; [...].

El DLE parece confirmar esta etimología y [afirma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6YMKxqN):

> Del lat. *catŭlus* 'cachorro'.

Te confirmo, por si lo sospechabas, que *[torionda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a5FKP70)* es la vaca en celo, y *[verrionda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bf1KnWc)* es la cerda en celo. Todos estos vocablos se forman con el sufijo *-iondo*:

> **[-iondo, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5BkJWn)**
>
> 1. suf. Forma adjetivos con el significado de 'en celo'. *Moriondo, toriondo, verriondo.*

Curiosamente, en el CORDE se encuentran casos hasta en el siglo XIII, bastante anteriores a la fecha propuesta por Corominas:

> *Pues quando qualquier d'estas sazones uinier, déxenlas folgar algunos días e non caçen ni corran fasta que sean cachondas, e después que foren cachondas, déxenlas folgar X días, e después échenles los canes, ca estos X días las deuen dexar folgar, por tal que se alinpien las madres d'ellas.*
>
> Abraham de Toledo, "Moamín. Libro de los animales que cazan", 1250 (España).