# Origen de los significados de "cachondo"

Tags: etimología, significado

> **[cachondo, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6YMKxqN)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. catŭlus 'cachorro'.
> ```
>
> 1. adj. vulg. Dicho de una perra: salida (‖ en celo).
> 2. adj. vulg. Dicho de una persona: Dominada por el apetito sexual. U. t. c. s.
> 3. adj. vulg. Que denota apetito sexual.
> 4. adj. coloq. Burlón, divertido, bromista. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 5. f. pl. Calzas acuchilladas.

El otro día en una conversación un poco extraña con un amigo llegamos a la duda de qué fue antes, ¿el sentido sexual o el sentido burlón de la palabra cachondo?

Pero no me quiero quedar ahi, por lo tanto la pregunta se divide en varias partes:

- ¿Qué significado es anterior?
- ¿Hay alguna relación entre los significados?
- ¿Cómo pasó a tener el significado mas nuevo?

Sé que normalmente tener varias preguntas en una no es recomendable, pero creo que guardan suficiente relación como para mantenerlas juntas.

Comment: [Muy relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26853/12637).

Comment: De hecho me la encontré mirando si esto ya se habia preguntado antes, pero no resolvia la duda que tenía en mente ;)

Answer (score 1):

El significado "Dicho de una persona: Dominada por el apetito sexual. U. t. c. s." viene claramente del primer significación de "Dicho de una perra: salida (‖ en celo)".

Su primer aparición en un diccionario es aquí:

> **Cachonda** perra que ſe para. *catuliens.tis.*
> **Cachonda** estar la perra. *catulio.is.*
>
> - 1495 NEBRIJA

Y no es hasta el siglo XIX que se reconoce la otra definición:

> **CACHONDEARSE,** v. r. Encenderse el apetito de lujuria. **Metafóricamente en Andalucía y otras partes se toma por burlarse.**
>
> **CACHONDO, DA.** adj. Se aplica al animal persona que tiene calentura venérea. Tam-bien se dice del sobradamente caloroso, y **en Andalucía y otras partes familiarmente al que es muy burlen.** La Academia dice que es adjetivo que se aplica á la perra salida, y usado en plural y como sustantivo femenino antiguamente, eran las calzas acuchilladas.
>
> - 1852 CASTRO Y ROSSI (A-COSTRA)

Comment: Y podrias investigar de donde viene este uso andaluz, y si está relacionado con el significado original? con eso quedaría todo respondido :) por lo pronto te voy a dar +1

Answer (score 0):

1) De un blog intitulado: **Andalú, fititú**  ..**yo no elegí nacer en Andalucía, simplemente tuve suerte!!**

> "cachondeo.  Dicen los habitantes de Zahara de los Atunes (Barbate,
>   Cádiz) que la palabra cachondeo proviene de ese lugar. Concretamente
>   del río Cachón, que desemboca en la localidad y en cuyas riberas los
>   almadraberos organizaban sus fiestas tras haber tenido una buena
>   pesca. Con los asaltos de los piratas berberiscos, era un sitio
>   peligroso donde vivir, de trabajo duro, donde prácticamente solo iban
>   los que estaban un tanto desesperados, incluso redimían pena de cárcel
>   por estar en las pesquerías. Aquel ambiente, se prestaba al juego de
>   azar, a mas de una pelea y también, cuando había dinero, a orgías de
>   alcohol y bromas. Así, ese tipo de organización festiva y desmadrada
>   recibió el nombre de cachondeo."

2) Otra explicación:

¿**De dónde surge el término ‘cachondeo’?**
**ALFRED LÓPEZ** 10 DE MARZO DE 2017

> "Por una parte nos encontramos con quienes defienden que el origen del término ‘cachondeo’ proviene de Cádiz, más concretamente de Zahara de los Atunes, una localidad bañada por el río Cachón y es precisamente éste el que dicen que dio pie a la palabra. Según cuentan los zahareños, en la rivera de este río era donde se juntaban los pescadores de atún (conocidos como almadraberos) y organizaban sus fiestas y jolgorios tras la jornada de trabajo." [...]
>
> "Pero tal y como indico al inicio de esta curiosidad, hay quien no está de acuerdo con esta explicación [la del Río Cachón] señalando que la raíz etimológica del término cachondeo está en la palabra ‘**cachorro**’. Y es por el **ruido y alboroto que ocasionan las crías de perros** lo que le dio origen. Esta tesis fue defendida por el experto **Joan Corominas** en su **Breve Diccionario Etimológico de la Lengua Española**. Cabe destacar que **el Diccionario de la RAE** en su entrada ‘cachondo’ señala el mismo origen etimológico aportado por Corominas."

[enlace para 1)](http://erandaluysuvocabulario.blogspot.com/2012/08/si-miramos-el-diccionario-el-espanol.html)
[enlace para 2)](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-el-termino-cachondeo/)

Mi opinión es "Solo sé que no sé nada" frente a éstos illustrísimos señores.  Y  mi propio esposo, un andaluz cien por cien, las utiliza, tanto "cachondo" como "cachondeo".

Comment: ¿Porque estáis diciendo que esta respuesta no va? "No hay que matar el mensajero." Los andaluces dicen con gran frequencia: Qué cachondeo. sin ningún sentido sexual.